# New Quota Template to 4TB

Tags: quota

Central Admin > Application > New Quota Template
I tried putting 4194304 (4 TB) but it trims the last digit thus making it ~400GB.

so I thought this must one of the PowerShell stuff and wanted to give this a try http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2010&Cmdlet=Set-SPQuotaTemplate

But quickly learned SPQuota or SPQuotaTemplate does not exists in my environment. I get "term get-spQuotatemplate is not recognized.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I found the issue with SPQuota. The WSP has to be installed on the farm. It's by Gary blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using the SharePoint 2010/2013 Management Shell. If you are just using the normal Power Shell editor, you can run the following cmdlet first:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Afterwards, just go with your typical SharePoint powershell cmdlet or functions.

Comment: Yeap. SP cmdlets are added using add-pssnapin method.

Comment: after the snap in has been added you are still getting the error?

Comment: Yes. I found the issue with SPQuota. The WSP has to be installed on the farm. It's by Gary http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/